# Is there a Racket builtin to repeat an element n times as a list?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I realize this is trivially to implement myself, but I was curious if Racket has a builtin or syntactic equivalent to the following in Python:

```py
>>> n = 5
>>> element = "arbitrary string"
>>> [element] * n
['arbitrary string', 'arbitrary string', 'arbitrary string', 'arbitrary string', 'arbitrary string']
```

If not, what is the idiomatic way to do this sort of thing in Racket? Right now my way of doing the above in Racket is:

```lisp
(let ((n 5)
      (element "arbitrary string"))
  (map (λ (x) element)
       (range n)))
```

Any suggestions are immensely appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't think so, I haven't been able to find something like this in the Racket documentation.

Comment: You can use `for/list` as another way to construct a list simply.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed, `(for/list [(range n)] element)` is at least much better than my `map` based approach. Thanks!

Comment: @seisvelas don't forget to write it up as an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python's `["arbitrary string"] * 5` can be translated to `(make-list 5 "arbitrary string")` in Racket.

However, that's often not what you want, because elements are *shared*. This is totally fine for immutable values, but for mutable values, it could have an undesired consequence:

In Python

```
>>> xs = [[]] * 5
>>> xs[0].append(1)
>>> xs
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

In Racket:

```
> (define xs (make-list 5 (box 0)))
> (set-box! (first xs) 1)
> xs
'(#&1 #&1 #&1 #&1 #&1)
```

In Python, you could use the list comprehension to avoid the problem:

```
>>> xs = [[] for x in range(5)]
>>> xs[0].append(1)
>>> xs
[[1], [], [], [], []]
```

In Racket, you can use `build-list`.

```
> (define xs (build-list 5 (thunk* (box 0))))
> (set-box! (first xs) 1)
> xs
'(#&1 #&0 #&0 #&0 #&0)
```

Here are ways that also avoid the problem:

```
(build-list 5 (thunk* (box 0)))
(for/list ([x (in-range 5)]) (box 0))

(for/list ([x (range 5)]) (box 0))
(map (thunk* (box 0)) (range 5))
```

The last two are not recommended, because it needs to create the list `(range 5)` first, which is inefficient (it's similar to Python's `["hello" for x in list(range(5))]`).

Note that `(thunk* v)` is equivalent to `(lambda (ignored...) v)`, which is the reason why you get "fresh" `v`, avoiding the element sharing problem. However, if you intentionally want to share elements, you can also use `(const v)` instead of `(thunk* v)`.

```
> (define xs (build-list 5 (const (box 0))))
> (set-box! (first xs) 1)
> xs
'(#&1 #&1 #&1 #&1 #&1)
```

Lastly, `build-list` in fact gives you the index as well. I used `thunk*` previously because for your problem, we don't need the index. However, if you need it, you can use it:

```
> (build-list 5 (lambda (x) (* 2 x)))
'(0 2 4 6 8)
```

Comment: `make-list` is exactly what I want, and the additional information about mutable data was also very interesting and noteworthy. Thanks for this excellent answer!

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `make-list`. Here `(make-list k v)` makes a list with `k` elements all of which are `v`. There is a similar functions `make-vector` that, well, makes vectors:

```
> (make-list 5 "foo")
'("foo" "foo" "foo" "foo" "foo")

 > (make-vector 5 1)
 '#(1 1 1 1 1)
```

Lookup both `make-list` and `build-list` and compare.